# Statistical data like display in website from large record set

Tags: mysql, web, statistics

I have 4 databases with tables having lots of data. My requirement is to show count of all the records in these tables on mouse hovering the corresponding div in UI(It is an asp.net website). Please note the count may change in every minute or in hour. (Means new records can be added or deleted from the table [using another application]). Now the issue is like, it is taking lot of time to get the count (since it has lots of data). So each mouse over, it is having a call to corresponding database and taking the count. Is there any better approach to implement this?

I am thinking of implementing something like as below.

http://www.worldometers.info/world-population/

But to change the figures like that in each second I need to have a call to the database. Right? (To get the latest count) Is there any better approach to show data like this statistics?

By the Way, I am using MySQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more details - what table engines you are using, how does your count query look like, etc.

But assuming that you are using InnoDB, and you are trying to run `count(*)` or `count(primary_id_column)`, you have to remember that InnoDB has clustered primary keys, that are stored with the data pages of the row itself, not in separate index pages, so the count will do full scan on the rows.

One thing you can try is to create additional, separate, not primary index on any unique column (like row's id etc,) and make sure (use explain query statement) that your count uses this index.

If this does not work for you, I would suggest to create separate table (for example with columns: table_name, row_count) to store counters in it and create triggers on insert and on delete on other tables (you need to count records in) to increment or decrement these values. From my experience (we monitor number of records in daily and hourly manners, on tables with hundreds of milions of records and heavy write load: ~150 inserts/sec) this is the best solution I have came up so far.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. triggers I also considered..But it will affect the database performance..rt?

Comment: It will, but simple incrementation/decrementation shouldn't be be noticable. How many inserts/updates do you have?

Comment: insert and update is happening from another application..its so frequent..every minute.

Comment: I don't know what hardware do you have, but a insert/update every minute is not that frequent. As I have written we have about 150 inserts every second (device tracking system) and the triggers work perfectly. If you want rapid information about rowcount, separate table with counters will be best solution.